# Setting up a detail view controller using a segue

Tags: objective-c, object, memory-management, ios5

**BACKGROUND:**

I have a custom UIViewController class where I populate a MKMapView with custom annotations.  When the user selects the annotation, details about that annotation are displayed, and a button is also present for the user to select and bring up another UIViewController with details about that point on the map.

**The Code:**

I initialize the new view controller by creating the class with a UserID (Note: `- (id) initWithUserID:(NSInteger) userID;` is declared in the header file of the SecondViewController:

```
@interface SecondViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger userID;

@end



@implementation RainFallDetailedViewController

@synthesize userID = _userID;


- (id) initWithUserID:(NSInteger) userID{

_userID = userID;
NSLOG(@"UserID: %i",self.userID); //correctly displays user id

return self;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear{
NSLOG(@"UserID: %i",self.userID); //userid is now 0
```

Creating the view controller is done when the button is pressed, and then immediately performs the segue to the second view controller:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {

if ([(UIButton*)control buttonType] == UIButtonTypeInfoLight){ //I'm looking for recognition of the correct button being pressed here.
    //SecondViewController is the second view controller with the detailed information about the map point.  
    //DataPoint is a custom class that contains the details regarding the map point.
    SecondViewController *detailedMapController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithUserID:((DataPoint *)view.annotation).userID]; 

    NSLOG(@"UserID: %i", ((DataPoint *)view.annotation).userID); //correctly displays userID

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PinDetail" sender:detailedMapController];


} 
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

Using NSLOG I'm able to confirm that the value is being passed correctly when creating the class.  However, when I go to use the property `userID` later on in the code (viewWillAppear), it's not longer there for me to use.  I'm assuming that there's a memory issue that I'm not taking care of but I can't seem to figure it out.  How do I ensure that the values/object I pass into a class upon creation stay there?

*Side Note: I originally tried, passing a `PinData` object, but ran into the same issue, so I know it's not a NSInteger problem.  I've also followed noa's suggestion and used `prepareForSegue` however, I get the same problem presented above*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The segue is responsible for instantiating the controller. Don't instantiate another one – it'll just be discarded, which is why the property values don't seem to stick.

To set up the view controller, override `-prepareForSegue:` instead, in the parent view controller:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender:(id) sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PinDetail"]) {
        SecondViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.userID = self.userID;
    }
}
```

Replace the last block of code above with this:

```
self.userID = ((RainFallDataPoint *)view.annotation).userID;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PinDetail" sender:self];
```

Comment: Ok, well, the view controller your instantiating is almost certainly not the one being displayed, which is likely why the property value doesn't seem to stick. Don't instantiate another view controller to pass as sender, just pass `self` or `mapView` instead.

Comment: but how do I then associate the correct userID with the new viewController.  Also, wouldn't that just create another view controller like the original?

Comment: I just checked.  Passing self as the sender gives me the same issue.

Comment: It looks like you should do it by overriding `prepareForSegue:`.

Comment: Using presentViewController just brings up a black screen :/

Comment: still gives me the same issue.  It passes the correct userID upon creation of the View Controller, but then that value is set to "0" afterwards.

Comment: It's because they're not the same instances. Try printing out `self` with `%p` in all both places and you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10562/discussion-between-kronos-and-noa)