# Annotation button switches from one mapView to another

Tags: ios, annotations, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue, mapbox

I am trying to figure out for a while now, how should I use the annotation button to switch 
to another mapView. The app I am working on uses MapBox - maps. I checked the exemples 
provided by them, but programmatically switching between two maps is there always achieved 
through tab bar (which is not the case I want to use).
I am working with storyboards and I understood it quit well, how the segue should be made 
in the Interface builder, but I think I am not managing with the programmatically integrated 
buttons on map views. I initiated 'id's in both header files and I proclaimed them in the 
Identity Inspector as well.

This is the part of the code, where I implement the RMMMapView with the annotation in the 
main View Controller - ViewController and it works perfectly:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

RMMapBoxSource *onlineSource = [[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:(([[UIScreen    mainScreen] scale] > 1.0) ? kRetinaMapID : kNormalMapID)];

_mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:onlineSource];

_mapView.tileSource = [[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:(([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] > 1.0) ? kRetinaMapID : kNormalMapID)];
_mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0,0);

 _mapView.adjustTilesForRetinaDisplay = YES;
_mapView.zoom = 4;

_mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

[self.view addSubview:_mapView];
_mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

[_mapView setConstraintsSouthWest:[_mapView.tileSource latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox].southWest
                            northEast:[_mapView.tileSource latitudeLongitudeBoundingBox].northEast];
RMPointAnnotation *annotation = [[RMPointAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:_mapView
                                                                coordinate:_mapView.centerCoordinate andTitle:@"Hello, world!"];
[_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

and this is the part, where I try to call the LowContentMap viewController, from the ViewController - main ViewController:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender:(id) sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Hello, world!"]) {
    //LowContentMap *lowContentMap = segue.destinationViewController;

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    LowContentMap *lowContentMap = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"lowContentMap"];
    lowContentMap.lcm = _vc;
}}
```

This is the part of the code, that should be filled in:

```
- (void)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView annotationView:(RMPointAnnotation *)annotation calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSomeViewController" sender:annotation];
}
```

It would be really great, if somebody would try to resolve the problem. 
I followed the discusion between Noa and Kronos at:
[Setting up a detail view controller using a segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337940/setting-up-a-detail-view-controller-using-a-segue/10338065#10338065)
but I still think, the part with the 'id' is something I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### **1. I think your problem is that you don't know how to display another viewController**

You should give the "View Controller Programming Guide" a good read, especially the part "Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers"

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

I also recommend to check out some of the awesome WWDC videos that show how to use ViewControllers.

### **2. How to create and display a viewController**

There are many ways to do it. E.g. using the storyboard to create and display the viewController, define a protocol in the child controller, override "performSegueWithIdentifier" to set the delegate and implement the protocol to dismiss the vc.

However, in your case, it seems to make sense to do it all programmatically. Thus, you need to:

**a) find the right place to add your action**

**b) alloc and init your view controller:**

```
MyController *myController = [[MyController alloc] init];
// setup as required, there should be at least a delegate (being able to dismiss the view)
myController.delegate = self;
```

If you have designed your viewController in a storyboard, you might want to use this alloc/init routine instead:

```
MyController *myController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyController"];
myController.delegate = self;
```

**c) display your new view controller;**
this depends on if you have a navigationController:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
```

...or if you want to present it modally:

```
[self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

**d) dismiss when done;**
when your other controller is done with whatever it does, it should inform its delegate (implement your own protocol!) that it's done and should be dismissed. The delegate is the original viewController that created (alloc'd/inited) the "myController":

```
// this method should be defined in a protocol and implemented in the vc that created (and owns) the child view controller
// typically, this is the parent view controller 
- (void)done {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

if you used a navigationController it's not -dismissViewControllerAnimated:, but

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

hope this helps to clarify things

Comment: Hallo Michael,thanks for replying. I overwrote the `-prepareForSegue` method in my `-tapOnCalloutAccessoryControl:`and after that I changed `-[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"switchToMap" sender:control];` to `[self presentViewController:lcm animated:YES completion:NULL];` Now it works. (I was trying all the time to make the communication trough segue, but my programmatically implemented segue didn't know the segue made via storyboard. I also tried working with customContainer viewController.)